# LinkedIn authentication in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to add LinkedIn login button for Google Chrome extension

What I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
    authorize: true
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
    }

    function getProfileData() {
        IN.API.Profile("me").result(ShowProfileData);
    }

    function ShowProfileData(profiles) {
        var member = profiles.values[0];
        var id=member.id;
    }
</script>

<script type="in/Login"></script>
```

I'm getting following errors:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following 
Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". 
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-JtzerZa6_Bfln3Mh09ym-xkVVJRSqpFLyfGorJRxIvY='), 
or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

I don't know how to add Google Chrome Extension to LinkedIn Application (where I list domains) - so that might be a problem. Otherwise, have anyone did this and how did you achieve the result?

Comment: Do you have to add something to the extension manifest, something that allows you to get scripts and data from linkedin.com ?